# How is this series evaluated?

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

I entered this series into Mathematica to see if it could be simplified and it managed to give a form in terms of the partial gamma function. However I do not know how it derives this formula and I am interested in knowing how something like that can be done.

$$\sum _{k=0}^n \frac{\log ^{n-k}(x)}{(n-1)^{k+1} x^{n-1} (n-k)!}=\frac{\;\Gamma (n+1,\;(n-1)\log  x) }{(n-1)^{n+1}\;n!}$$

I presume that the following series is used
$$\Gamma(s,x) = (s-1)!\, e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Where $s$ is an integer.

However after some manipulation I could not even get the orignal sum from the answer.

Comment: In general Mathematica is proprietary. So unless you work there and see the source code, you may never know. Mathematica (and other software like PARI) pulls not only on knowledge of power series but on much more obscure results. There are many a PhD earned proving obscure results that are now embedded into PARI GP and I imagine that Mathematica has picked up on these and any other results it can get it's hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the series
\begin{align}
S(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\ln^{n-k}(x)}{(n-1)^{k+1} x^{n-1} (n-k)!}
\end{align}
where by reversing the order of summation the series becomes
\begin{align}
S(x) &= x^{1-n} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\ln^{k}(x)}{k! \, (n-1)^{n-k+1}} \\
&= \frac{x^{1-n}}{(n-1)^{n+1}} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{[(n-1) \, \ln(x)]^{k}}{k!}.
\end{align}
Now from the incomplete gamma function series 
\begin{align}
\Gamma(s,y) = (s-1)!\, e^{-y} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{y^k}{k!}
\end{align} 
it can be seen that, where $s = n+1$ and $y =(n-1) \, \ln(x)$, 
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1, (n-1) \, \ln(x)) = n! \, x^{1-n} \, \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(n-1)^{k} \, \ln^{k}(x)}{k!}
\end{align}
and leads to the desired result
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{\ln^{n-k}(x)}{(n-1)^{k+1} x^{n-1} (n-k)!}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1, \, (n-1)\ln(x)) }{(n-1)^{n+1} \, n!}
\end{align}