# Evaluating $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{e^{n-1}(n-k)!(n-1)^{k-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

**Major Update**

There has been a major error in one of my calculations, helpfully pointed out by   doraemonpaul.
The lower limit for the second summation has been changed to $k=0$ rather than $k=1$.
This has mostly deleted all my work on this summation so I am starting from scratch once more. This may however reveal a better summation to evaluate. Who knows.

---

The series is as follows

> $$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{e^{n-1}(n-k)!(n-1)^{k-1}}$$

---

Comment: Misread what was written.

Comment: For the first part, you may consider http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.4.E8

Comment: Where did you encounter the double sum?

Comment: @Alyosha [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508829/integrating-int-0ex1-x-dx?lq=1)

Comment: The question has problem as it appears the term of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^0$ .

Comment: @doraemonpaul Thank you for pointing out the error. It has now been resolved. I credited your help in the original post.

Comment: @Alizter: Are you sure about the bounds of $n$? Using Maple, I get that the first sum is (n-1)*hypergeom([1, -n], [], -1/(n-1))/(exp(n-1)*factorial(n)) but it has a singularity at n=1 ...

Answer (score 1):

In fact the double sum is undefined as the term of $n=1$ has the denominator $0$ , as explained in [How to find $\int x^{1/x}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459147).